# How to use scrypt or Argon for Openldap version < 2.4.5

Tags: passwords, hashing, password-management, ldap

I know that support for `Argon2` was released with `OpenLdap 2.4.5` according to this link `https://bugs.openldap.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8575`, but what if I want to use it with a previous version like `2.4.4` is there a way of doing this? Also if `argon` is not possible is there a way of using `scrypt` for password hashing?

Comment: Related question [What is the best way to store passwords in OpenLDAP?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/87061/3365) suggests OpenLDAP historically doesn't offer much in terms of advanced password hashing algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Since the argon2 support is modular, you can try compiling and loading the module into your 2.4.4 installation in the same way - once compiled, load it:

```
4) Edit your slapd.conf (eg. /etc/ldap/slapd.conf), and add:

moduleload ...path/to/pw-argon2.so

5) Restart slapd.
```

It is the nature of modular code that it should run under earlier versions that support the same modular framework, and it's a reasonable assumption that 2.4.4 and 2.4.5* are close enough in that respect... as long as you have a safe place to test, "you might as well try it."

The `README` file in openldap source code directory `contrib/slapd-modules/passwd/argon2` also contains instructions for generating hashes and testing openldap integration.

I would strongly recommend testing this on a standalone test instance before attempting to integrate it into a production instance.

Comment: Thanks gowenfawr, I will try that out right now!